# segue not working causing app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime-error, segue, unrecognized-selector

my code is breaking on the segue. the segue was modal at first , i tried to change it to push but its still not working  my code is the following :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([[segue identifier ] isEqualToString:@"detailLoanSeg"]){
    detailLoan *theController=[segue destinationViewController];
    theController.time=_time;
    theController.cuurLoan=_cuurLoan;
    theController.currName=_currName;
   }
}
```

and the error in xcode is :

```
 014-05-07 04:38:11.257 LoanCalc[1561:a0b] -[UIViewController setTime:]: 
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa05f1f0  
 2014-05-07 04:38:11.266 LoanCalc[1561:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
 exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setTime:]: 
 unrecognized selector    sent to instance 0xa05f1f0'
```

Comment: Check your _time variable.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like, in storyboard, you forgot to indicate the custom class of the destination view controller.  In storyboard, select that destination VC, click the third inspector from the right and set it's Custom Class to "detailLoan" (which violates class naming convention).

The error is that your destination vc is a generic `UIViewController`, which naturally doesn't implement the `setTime`: method.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the destination class is your View Controller and not a UINavigationController?  Put a breakpoint and check what theController class is.  Also make sure that the view controller in the Storyboard has its class set from the default UIViewController to your custom subclass.  It's almost certainly one of those two issues.

Comment: do you expect UINavigationController to handle the `setTime:` message?

Comment: No, I'm saying if the destination is a UINavigationController (which it would be if the segue terminates on a UINavigationController like during a model presentation) then he doesn't want the destination view controller, he wants the rootViewController of the destination view controller.  Common mistake.  I'm assuming his custom UIViewController subclass has a property on it that will accept the properties he is passing as is customary in these cases.

Comment: It's good advice but for a different mistake, check the error log: UIViewController is the recipient of the unrecognized selector.

Comment: no, you are not saying that. you don't explain any of the implications. your answer would better had been a comment.

Comment: I said its one of the two issues I pointed out which includes not setting the subclass from the Storyboard.  I see that it is almost certainly that but I did also mention that possibility in my answer as those are the two reasons why this usually happens.

Comment: And yes I noticed now that it says its a UIViewController which I originally glossed over and didn't catch.  But the answer I gave also addressed the custom subclass not being set.